# Dll cannot loaded when running application from another application

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I have two application, first is my main application and second is application to call main application. I want to run my first application from second application. why when my first application was calling from second application, the DLL could not be loaded?

Can someone tell me and help me?

Comment: So you want to run console-application from winforms application - is it correct?

Comment: both of my application is console application. i want to run console application from console application

Comment: also add same dll file into your second application and try :)

Answer (score 1):

Launch console application from another application:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

 ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 processInfo.Arguments = "Some argument";
 processInfo.FileName = "Your console .exe path"; 
 int exitCode;

 using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
 {
            process.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
 }
```

Comment: Console app argument (if any).

Comment: anyway, I already do like that. but my first application DLL could not loaded

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Process ExternalProcess = new Process();
                ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication.exe";
                ExternalProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                ExternalProcess.Start();
                ExternalProcess.WaitForExit();
```

if this won't work, kindly share the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with @Sudipta Maiti answer and I add dll into second application, and I store both off my application in one folder.
:)

thank you